# Calculating resistance value for voltage range

Tags: power-electronics, high-voltage, nixie

I have been working on a DIY Nixie tube clock.  Looking at the schematic for my specific Nixie tubes, the ignition voltage is 170V. This led me to buy a 12V - 170V boost converter. Using this I can power on the Nixie tubes, but the main issue is that the most efficient voltage to run the tube at once it has been ignited is 145V.

I can't remember where, but someone told me that I should use a resistor. I am not entirely sure why, I am quite new to electrical engineering so it would be helpful if someone could explain why I need a resistor and how to calculate it.

Comment: 12V to 170V is a boost converter.  A buck converter goes from a high voltage to a lower voltage.  A boost converter goes from a low voltage to a higher one.

Comment: You would need to know how much current flows through the tube at 145V to calculate a resistor value.

Comment: You need to know the current at which the nixie tube runs at to be able to calculate the resistance. Or simply try few different resistances to find out which ends up having 145V at the tube while supply is 170V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes a certain minimum voltage to make a Nixie tube light up.

Once it is lit, the current controls the brightness.  More current = brighter light.

More current also means shorter life span for the tube.

You want a balance between useful brightness and long life time.

The ignition voltage will push a rather large current through the tube, making it rather bright and shortening the lifetime of the tube.

If you know the rated operating current of the tube, then you can figure out a series resistor.

You need the source voltage (Vs,) the operating voltage (Vo,) and the operating current (Io.)

The series resistor is then given by \$ R = \frac{V_s - V_o}{I_o}\$.

The required information should be in the datasheet for the tube.

If you have the datasheet, though, then you probably won't have to calculate anything.  The needed resistor value will be given.

Like in this example:

[image]

The "Test conditions" give the operating voltage and the value of a series resistor.  Problem solved.

It also includes the typical operating current if you'd like to do your own calculations.

Comment: Thankyou very much for that detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a tube with no current flow, and you apply 170 volts, this will cause a current to flow. If you maintain the "ignition voltage" on the tube, the current will increase as the temperature of the tube increases and this could cause the tube to "run away" and result in damage to the tube. If you put a properly sized resistor in series with the tube, you will apply the 170 volts to the tube before current starts to flow but once the tube gets started, the current will cause a voltage drop across the resistor and lower the "applied" voltage on the tube thereby limiting the current through the tube at a safe level. If you measure the current through the tube when you apply 145 volts, then you can calculate the resistance required to give you that 25 volt drop. Don't forget to calculate the wattage required for the resistor and size it appropriately.